# jQuery $.ajax call to GitHub Oauth API return an unidentified error

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, github

First of all this is the code:

```
var requestAuthUri = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token';

var ajaxArgs = {
    type        :   'POST',
    url         :   requestAuthUri,
    headers     :   {
        'Accept'    :   'application/json'
    },
    data        :   {
        'client_id'         :       this.args['client_id'],
        'client_secret'     :       this.args['client_secret'],
        'code'              :       queryVars['code']
    },
    dataType    :   'json',
    error       :   function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

        console.log(errorThrown);

            alert( textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown );
        }
    };

    console.log(ajaxArgs);

    $.ajax( ajaxArgs ).done( function( response ) {

        console.log( response );

    });
```

These are the server reply headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2013 08:42:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-Frame-Options: deny
Set-Cookie: logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jul-2033 08:42:09 GMT; HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 18
Etag: "c4d5365a37fa466698cb5dc6e66f61e3"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

And these are the client headers:

```
POST /login/oauth/access_token HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://site.it/app/?code=xxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 111
Origin: http://site.it
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The problem is that the body content is empty, an unindentified (empty errorThrown) error is triggered by $.ajax and i'm struggling figuring out why.

What i've allready tried:

- changing from json to xml and text dataType
- sending data as `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- set crossDomain to true

Am i out of luck?! :)

Comment: Can you please add the full request (headers + body) that is being made? You can use the same tool you are using to get the response headers.

Comment: I've updated the question with the request headers, regarding the body: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id xxx
client_secret xxx
code xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that queryVars['code'] really holds the correct code given from GitHub.
Then, try text/plain as response instead, and skip the Accept-header, just to see if you get any response.

The error thrown you get basicly tells you, that you've got an malformed JSON-response from the server. So try just to receive the basic reply at first, then move on to get it in JSON-format.

Comment: Checked queryVars['code'], tried text dataType and deleted Accept-header... Still the same: response 200 with no body. (Ps. In both case no parse error has been triggered).

Comment: Which browser are you using? This can be a cross-domain related problem. You see, it is forbidden to send JSON-strings cross-domain in browsers, due security. The workaround is JSONP (JSON with Padding). However, that is a bit tricky. I'd suggest you try to send a CURL-request instead. If you want it async (which I assume), just put the CURL in a php-file, and call that one with $.ajax().

Comment: Actually i can't... i'll be using the code in a iOS App :( The matter is that i tried others query (with both POST and GET) and github API does great. The problem is only with the Oauth Auth. Moreover i've already tried JSONP but with lousy results (from a POST the request become a GET...). Do you know where i can find more info about it, apart from the official documentation?

Comment: You cannot use JSONP to make POST requests, it is possible only to make GET request using JSONP. Also, if you use JSONP - you cannot set any HTTP headers. (This is because JSONP basically works by constructing a <script> tag, and you can only make normal GET requests using a <script> tag).

Comment: Thank you both guys, googling i found out that other people had my  same issue. The only work around (as i could find out) is to create a little proxy file in php as stated by Eric. http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/javascript/github-oauth-login-browser-side.html